# Decoding ptrace Registers

Tags: linux, struct, bit, strace, ptrace

I'm wondering where in the contents/members of

```
`struct user_regs_struct ur`
```

which is filled in by a call to

```
ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, &ur); // get registers
```

I can extract the information about whether a traced child process syscall is currently *entering* or *exiting*. After some testing my conclusion so far is that the lower 8-bits of struct member `ax` is equal to `0xda` for exits. I'm however unsure whether this is a correct general conclusion so I'm ask whether this is documented anywhere.

In the strace sources I have found the bitmask define `TCB_INSYSCALL` which is probably what I'm looking for but I can't decode where the source of the information (some member of `user_regs_struct`?) is read.